# How to load third-party implementations at run-time

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a .Net application to manage and install mods. The application itself shouldn't be able to install mods for any particular game but should be able to call 3rd-party extensions to do so.

Let's say my mod manager expects an implementation of the given interface:

```
interface IGameManager {
    // Deploy a modding configuration to the targeted game
    void Deploy();
    // Remove all managed mods from the targeted game
    void Purge();
    // ...
}
```

And someone else, working on a different code base, implement IGameManager to manage a specific game:

```
class MinecraftManager: IGameManager {
    // ...
}
```

Then this person compiles it, publishes it and everyone could simply feed this extension to the main mod manager so it can manage their mods for the targeted game.

But how? Is there a way for my application to safely load and use such third-party implementations at run-time? And how to facilitate the making of third-party extension (e.g. giving an interface to build on but more elegantly and maintenance-friendly)?

Edit 1: Invalid syntax in MinecraftManager signature

Comment: Look at the Assembly class and its Load* methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out dotNet 4 already have an extensibility framework ([Documentations here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/)), which is cleaner and safer than using `Assembly.Load()`.

Here's the snippet I use to load my plugins from a given directory, if anyone encounter the same problem:

```cs
// Where T is the type you want to retrieve from the assemblies
private static IEnumerable<Lazy<T>> LoadExternalAssemblyFromPath<T>(string path, string pattern) {
    CreateDirectoryIfDoesntExist(path);
    AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(path, pattern));

    CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    return container.GetExports<T>();
}

// Usage:
LoadExternalAssemblyFromPath("C:/path/to/plugins", "*.dll");
```

Regarding the implementation of such plugin, Kouvarakis' solution on the matter is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You are essentially trying to design a plugin system. There are many implementations that you could reuse but the general idea is that:

1. You need your manager to be able to discover extensions. There are many ways to do that but the simplest and most used approach is to place extension assemblies under a well known directory in the file system. Then your manager can enumerate the assemblies in that folder by enumerating the files (or if you prefer that each extension has it own subfolder enumerate the subfolders)
2. Load the assembly. For that you will use one of the `Assembly.Load..` methods. Since it is not possible to unload assemblies, you may want to first load the assembly for reflection only and once you decide that the assembly is valid you can load it in the `ApplicationDomain` in order to use it.
3. Use relfection to enumerate all classes of the assembly you just loaded and find the ones that implement the right interface (`IGameManager`). Altenatively you can require that extensions contains an "entry point" class of known name, then look for that class by name (using reflection).
4. Create an instance of the class(es) and use it (perhaps also keep it in a collection of loaded extensions)

Regarding the interface that extensions must implement: You should put the interface (and any other supporting interfaces) in a separate assembly. The assembly should contain only interfaces, no implementation. You can then publish the assembly. Once published the interface should never change.

If you need to add functionality you should create a new interface. This way old versions of the manager will work with newer versions of an extension (that is designed to implement the new functionality as well). Also your manager can determine which interfaces are implemented by an extension and act accordingly (thus maintaining compatibility). If the new functionality is mandatory, your manager should discard any extension that does not implement both interfaces.

Comment: I'm sure I'm about to say something wrong, but aren't assembly pre-compiled, like a .dll? And since interfaces aren't actual instructions, are they exempt during compilation? If didn't got it wrong, how can someone use an assembly to implement an interfaces?

Comment: An interface in CLR is not just a compile time artifact (like e.g. in Typescript). It gets compiled into the assembly. Assemblies contain more than jsut IL instructions. There are all sorts of metadata included that make loading and linking assemblies possible. Interface-only assemblies are in fact a very common thing in .NET (Java as well AFAIK) and used regularly to decouple the implementation from the consumer of the interface.